# Rails: Cannot Parse JSON object neither with hash key or index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, parsing, google-maps

Weird question tag but still wanted to ask because even though it looks easy no matter what I've tried I could not accomplish

I'm trying to parse duration between to points from a URL given by Google Maps directions API. Thanks an answer I've received from here I was able to capture the JSON object and get to the duration object however no matter what I did I could not get the inner values "text" or "value" from the "duration" attribute.

Here is the response;

```
{
  "text" : "6 mins",
  "value" : 373
}
```

And here is the code I've written in rails

```
@request = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=40.983204,29.0216549&destination=40.99160908659266,29.02334690093994&sensor=false'))
    hash = JSON.parse @request
    duration = hash['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['duration']

    respond_to do |format|
    format.html {render :index}
    format.json {render json: duration}
    end
```

**Note:**  Of course, the **[0]** and **['text']** methods have been tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first thing you need to define duration as an instance variable to have it available in your views (if this is where you need to use it)

```
@duration = hash['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['duration']
```

Comment: Doesn't make sense at all. I'm not showing the variable with a view. Thus I do not need the define it as a global variable.

Comment: so the problem is that you have data in the duration variable but are not able to get them out?

Comment: Yeah. Duration variable seems to be a hash but I cannot get the inner values "text" or "value" even though I try to call them as ['text'] or [0]. None works.

Answer (score 0):

duration["text"] and duration["value"] didn't work?

```
    1.9.3p194 :001 > require 'net/http'
     => true 
    1.9.3p194 :002 > require 'json'
     => true 
    1.9.3p194 :003 > @request = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=40.983204,29.0216549&destination=40.99160908659266,29.02334690093994&sensor=false'));
    1.9.3p194 :004 >   hash = JSON.parse @request;
    1.9.3p194 :005 >   duration = hash['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['duration']
     => {"text"=>"6 mins", "value"=>373} 
    1.9.3p194 :006 > duration["text"]
     => "6 mins" 
    1.9.3p194 :007 > duration["value"]
     => 373
```

Comment: The same is in rails 3.2.8 in empty app's console